# Regex: Disallow certain repeated characters

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to validate strings. The strings are allowed to contain any characters except `'!'`, `'{'`, `'}'`, or `'::'`.

Typically I would use a negated character set like `[^!{}]`, but I can't figure out how to get a negated-character-set approach like that to allow one `:` but disallow two `::`

Comment: what programming language are u using? u don't need regex for that.

Comment: It's part of a PEG grammar

Comment: So I am constrained to regex as an overall approach

Comment: 1) `^(?!.*::).*:`, 2) `(?<!:):(?!:)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that is a good solution, but I should have been more specific--I need to match substrings, and `::` is allowed elsewhere, just not in the substring. It's part of a grammar, so it's really constrained.

Comment: @Marcos I forgot to tag you above